# Applications of Julia in Chemistry and Molecular Physics?

Tags: computational-physics, reference-request, computational-chemistry, julia

I was wondering if there are any Theoretical & Computational Chemistry (MM, QM) codes or publications out there that are based primarily on the Julia programming language?

Answer (score 4):

It's an entire programming language with a large community, so it's pretty much impossible to dig up all examples of its usage in these fields, but I can point to a few resources to get you started. These are ones that come to mind, but note I'm not a theoretical or quantum chemist so I am not very familiar with this area.

- [QuantumOptics.jl](https://qojulia.org/) has a community around QO modeling and research.
- [DiffEqBiological.jl](https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqBiological.jl) is a chemical reaction network DSL for SDEs, ODEs, and continuous-time Markov chains.
- [Molly.jl](https://github.com/jgreener64/Molly.jl) is a molecular dynamics engine.
- [HomotopyContinuation.jl](https://www.juliahomotopycontinuation.org/) is made by a bunch of chemists IIRC for fast bifurcation analysis on polynomial systems.
- [Yao.jl](https://github.com/QuantumBFS/Yao.jl) is for quantum algorithms.

Lots of publications that use Julia cite the Julia paper (but not all of course), so a [Google Scholar citation search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22&sciodt=0,22&cites=12373977815425691465&scipsc=) might be helpful with this as well.

Comment: For future readers, this question was also asked/answered near simultaneously on [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/503/7)